# Simplify $\int udv-\int vdu$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, integration-by-parts

Is there any way to simplify $\int udv-\int vdu$?

Something related is that $\int udv+\int vdu$ can clearly be simplified to $uv$, and I am wondering if it can be done for $\int udv-\int vdu$

Comment: Consider $\frac uv$. It's not correct, but it's close. Maybe it leads to an answer.

Answer (score 3):

We know that by the integration by parts formula we have $$\int u dv = uv -\int v du $$ $$\Rightarrow \int u dv -\int v du =uv -2\int v du = 2\int u dv -uv $$ I don't think there exists a nice simplification of the result. Hope it helps.

Comment: This answer *proves* that there cannot exist any "nice simplification of the result".

Answer (score 1):

Every expression like $df=f'(x)dx$ called *Exact Differential* ([Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExactDifferential.html)) that your example is an exact differential
$$d(uv)=u\,dv+v\,du$$
Some exact differentials you may use to simplify expression like $u\,dv-v\,du$ are 
$$d\Big(\frac{v}{u}\Big)=\frac{u\,dv-v\,du}{u^2}$$
$$d\Big(\arctan\frac{v}{u}\Big)=\frac{u\,dv-v\,du}{u^2+v^2}$$
$$d\Big(\ln\frac{v}{u}\Big)=\frac{u\,dv-v\,du}{u\,v}$$
In these cases you need to **multiply** an extra expression which convert yours to one exact differentials.